# How do I apply SLOCC transformations, in terms of matrices?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

The 2-qubit entangled state $|\phi_1\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|00\rangle + \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}|11\rangle$ is SLOCC equivalent (equivalent under Stochastic Local Operations and Classical Communication) to the Bell State $|\phi_0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|00\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|11\rangle$, because all 2-qubit entangled states are SLOCC equivalent.

However, SLOCC transformations on n-qubit states are elements of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})^{n}$, in other words ordered tuples of matrices with determinant 1. For the 2-qubit case, I will write these two matrices as $(A,B)$.

Consider the $2\times2$ matrix $\psi$ with entries $ij$ defined by $|\psi\rangle=\sum \psi_{ij} |ij\rangle$. Then I think that the SLOCC transformation $(A,B)$ is applied to this state by $\psi'_{ij} = \sum_{a,b} A_{ia}B_{jb}\psi_{ab} = A\psi B^{\mathrm T}$ (like equation 3 in [Miyake 2004](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0401023)). But this is just a matrix multiplication by two matrices with determinant one, and thus leaves the determinant of the matrix $\psi$ unchanged...

...but the determinant of the matrix corresponding to $|\phi_1\rangle$ is $\frac{i}{2}$, and the determinant of the matrix corresponding to $|\phi_0\rangle$ is $\frac{1}{2}$, and these two determinants are *not* equal.

I have clearly went wrong somewhere; where, and what should I have done?

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: in this case you would have $|\phi_1\rangle=(I\otimes S)|\phi_0\rangle$ with $S$ the unitary $S=1/\sqrt2 \operatorname{diag}(1,i)$. This does not have determinant one, hence your observation. You can however fix this by simply using $S'\equiv -iS$, which would have trace one, and produce a state equivalent to $|\phi_1\rangle$, only differing from it by a phase